# redirect after deletion of user drupal

Tags: drupal-7, rule

I want to redirect to a certain page after deletion of user account.

WHAT I TRIED:

rules method:
event: after user account has been deleted
action: redirect to certain page

using fomr_alter:

```
if($form_id == "user_cancel_confirm_form")
    $form["#submit"][] = 'mymodule_delete_account_submit';

function(mymodule_delete_account_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_goto("mypage");
}
```

but its not redirecting i also tried to use `$form_state['redirect'] = "mypage"`

any workaround? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an **internal path** when using **$form_state['redirect']** like this:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = "internal-path-to-mypage";
```

Comment: thanks for that quick reply, but, i used internal page, i used `content/333`, but is not redirecting... it returns back to the list of users

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
header('Location: ' . $url); // with base_url
drupal_exit();
```